# The emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have a vm created in Azure, Windows Server 2012, x64 with Visual Studio 2015.
I'm trying the Weather application example from the site  https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/
When I try to start the application running the emulator VS Emulator 5 KitKat (4.4) I have errors with internet connection but I actually can connect to the internet.

Just after launch the application I get this message:

[image]

I hit Accept and then, after display the screen, I get next messages (Although the message is talking about Hyper-V, i´m using my MSDN account and Azure)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to start the application running the emulator VS Emulator 5 KitKat (4.4) I have errors with internet connection but I actually can connect to the internet.

VS Emulators run as Hyper-V Virtual Machines. And if you are already in a Windows Server 2012 VM environment, it is not possible to to start another VM inside of it.

In Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10 VM it is possible to start an VM inside. For details, please refer to [Enable Nested Virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting).

Comment: Emulator runs in Windows 10